# Vue force component to render to DOM before it is visible

Tags: vue.js

I have a dialog with elements that I want to access *before* it is visible to the user. However, the dialog contents (Vue component) are only accessible to Vue once the dialog is visible. Is there a way to ensure the elements within my component are rendered to DOM before it is visible?

I have tried variations of nextTick and forceUpdate with no luck.

Comment: Would you please send the dialog codes?
It's related to whereby you handle show/hide dialog contents

Answer (score 0):

*elements that I want to access before it is visible to the user* sounds like you are probably doing something in "not Vue way" but sure, you can have your component rendered in DOM but still not visible by using [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)

Comment: After reading the docs, v-show does indeed seem to match what I'm looking for, thank you!